# Objective-c NSViewController keyDown event not work

Tags: events, keydown, nsevent

I found this code. Events for `mouseDown` work well, but not for `keyDown`, only system sounds. Code inside my `ViewController` class.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES ;
}

- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow
{
    [self.window makeFirstResponder: self];
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSString  *characters = [event characters];
    int  key = [characters characterAtIndex: 0];
    NSLog(@">> %s key %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,key);
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@">> %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__) ;
    NSLog(@"acceptsFirstResponder = %hhd", [self acceptsFirstResponder]) ;
}
```